# Patch the standalone redefinition of document environment in order to automatically add some extra code?

Tags: standalone, patching

**Edit.** I rewrite my question as I simplified too much my real problem and the example didn't reflect it.

In the following MWE,

- a custom class `myclass.cls`:

  1. defines a custom `\maketitle` macro (`\mymaketitle`) that starts a `multicols` environment after the usual `\maketitle`
  2. automatically ends the `multicols` environment at the end of the document,
- a (complete) subfile (`sub\jobname.tex`) makes use of the custom class and the custom `\mymaketitle`,
- a 1<sup>st</sup> main file has the same content as the subfile.
- by contrast to the 1<sup>st</sup> main file, a 2<sup>nd</sup> main file inputs the subfile instead of having the same content: though the subfile is complete, it shouldn't be a problem as the custom class loads the `standalone` package.

Both the 1<sup>st</sup> main and the sub file compile like a charm but the compilation of the 2<sup>nd</sup> main file fails with the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{multicols} on input line 5 ended by \end{document}.
```

except if what makes the subfile compilable on its own:

```
  \documentclass{myclass}
  \begin{document}
  ...
  \end{document}
```

is removed.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Class file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{standalone}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
%
\LoadClass{article}
%
\newcommand{\mymaketitle}{%
  \maketitle
  \begin{multicols}{2}
}
%
\AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Sub file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}{sub\jobname.tex}
  \documentclass{myclass}
  \begin{document}
  \title{Foo Bar}
  \author{Bar Foo}
  \mymaketitle
  Foo bar bar foo.
  \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Main file 1
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{myclass}
%
\begin{document}
\title{Foo Bar}
\author{Bar Foo}
\mymaketitle
Foo bar bar foo.
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Main file 2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{myclass}
%
\begin{document}
\input{sub\jobname}
\end{document}
```

I guess the failure of the compilation of the 2<sup>nd</sup> main file comes from the fact the `document` environment is redefined by the `standalone` package to be a simple TeX-group, hence the:

```
\AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}
```

from the custom class is now ignored.

Hence my question: is it possible to patch the `standalone` redefinition of `document` environment in order to automatically add some extra code (here `\end{multicols}`)?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. When I add `\AtEndDocument{\bigskip Good bye everybody!}` to the sub-file and compile the sub-file the text is there.

Comment: Oooops, sorry for the noise: I simplified too much my real problem and the example didn't reflect it. I edited the question with the hope it is clearer now.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the redefinitions of standalone. You would run into the same error if you would put an `\end{foo}` in your subfile.

Comment: Actually it looks as if standalone contains suitable code. Try `\RequirePackage[group=false]{standalone}`.

Comment: There is no point at all in `\RequirePackage{mwe}`.

Comment: @cfr Okay, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if standalone contains suitable code. Try `\RequirePackage[group=false]{standalone}`.